# XAML and HTML compatible subscript or (and) superscript text

Tags: c#, html, xaml, uwp

Is it possible to have a string incorporating all the formatting required to output text with subscript or (and - that is simultaneously) superscript designations?

I want to have a single resource file with such designations to share it between various application types (desktop, web, mobile (UWP at least), etc.) so I can show them in GUI in the same manner.

If not, how can I store a text with such designations (sub- and superscript) and then show it in XAML or HTML?

Maybe I should have some custom class (say, inside the model tier) with properties like Value, SubscriptText, SuperscriptText and then accommodate this class to each case (say, inside the view model tier, or inside the view tier like XAML or HTML), or is there a better solution?

**UPDATE-------------------------------------------------------------**

All of this is needed for me to show formulas' designations like

ω<sub>max</sub>

in UWP and WPF GUI and in my site (HTML).

I haven't found a more convenient way than just split designation in parts (designation itself, subscription part, and so on), store these parts somewhere (.resx files, for example), and then use custom helpers on each GUI tier to obtain these parts and show them in GUI.

For now I decided to store each such a designation in .resx files (inside .NET Standard library) in the manner:

- MyValueDesignation: ω
- MyValueSubscript: max

Then I created custom attribute DesignationAttribute with properties Designation and Subscript, in which I store the designation's parts on a model tier (or where this attribute is applied). I use it like so:

```
[Designation(
    resourceType: typeof(Resources.Models.Designations),
    designation: "MyValueDesignation",
    subscript: "MyValueSubscript")]
public double MyValue { get; set; }
```

Then I obtain these designation's parts from DesignationAttribute in each GUI tier and put them inside GUI through custom helpers. For example, on the HTML tier I created an extension for HtmlHelper to obtain designation's parts and return them as prepared HTML string like

```
<span>ω<sub>max</sub></span>
```

On the WPF tier I also used custom helper to return markup like so:

```
<TextBlock>
  <Span>
    ω
  </Span>
  <Span
    Style="{StaticResource labelSubscript}">
      max
  </Span>
</TextBlock>
```

**UPDATE-------------------**

Another solution is to use Unicode symbols like this:

```
string mySubscriptAndSuperscriptString = "ω\u2098\u2090\u2093\u00B2";
```

[Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qCemI0)

or even type (or copy and paste) it in the Visual Studio directly:

```
string mySubscriptAndSuperscriptString = "ωₘₐₓ\u00B2";
```

which all produce ω<sub>max</sub><sup>2</sup>.

Downside of this is you have to type all the characters by copy-pasting them one by one or typing the full Unicode code for each character. And you can't have subscript and superscript simultaneously (one strictly vertical under/above another), so that "power of 2" would be located not to the right of "max", but strictly above it.

Comment: Did you just mean you want to show text with subscript format in a UWP GUI?  Why XAML and HTML both required? What you have done?

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT I added some clarification at the end of my question - see "UPDATE".